# Busca por termos fora de ordem php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ola pessoal estava dando uma pesquisada por aqui e gostaria de saber como faço para pesquisar termos fora de ordem

exemplo possuo uma tabela com o seguinte nome: nome_prod

nela esta um exemplo de nome:

CARTÃO DE VISITA - 4X0- COUCHE BRILHO 250GRS / COM CANTO ARREDONDADO

gostaria de poder fazer uma busca onde pudesse pesquisar por exemplo:

cartão 4x0 couche arredondado

e aparece o resultado, ha alguma forma de fazer isso?
segue o meu codigo:

```
<?php
// Incluir aquivo de conexão
include("Connections/conn2.php");

// Recebe o valor enviado
$valor = $_GET['valor'];

// Procura titulos no banco relacionados ao valor
$sql = $conn1->query("SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE nome_prod LIKE '%".$valor."%' OR codigo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' ORDER BY codigo_prod ASC");


echo "<div class=\"row\" style=\"justify-content:center;\">\n";
if ($sql) {
while ($prod = $sql->fetch_object()) { 

    $variavel = $prod->tipo_prod;
    $imgse = $conn1->query("SELECT `arquivo` FROM cad_prodrutos_tipo_prod WHERE tipo_prod='$variavel' "); 
    if ($imgse->num_rows > 0) { 
    while($imgrow = $imgse->fetch_object()) {



$variavel_limpa = strtolower( preg_replace("/[ -]+/", "-", strtr(utf8_decode(trim($variavel)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ"),"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC-")) );

        $valor = $prod->valor_uni;

$Preco = number_format($valor,2,",",".");

    ?>

<?php

    echo "     <div class=\"card_prod card_prod--19\" >\n";
echo "        <div class=\"card_prod__header card_prod__header--19\">\n";
echo "          <div class=\"card_prod__watermark\" data-watermark=\"plus\"></div>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "          <img src=\"assets/img/brand/logo.png\" alt=\"Nike\" class=\"card_prod__logo \">\n";
echo "\n";
echo "             <span class=\"card_prod__price \">R$ $Preco </span>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "          <h1 class=\"card_prod__title text-white \">$prod->nome_prod</h1>\n";
echo "          <span class=\"card_prod__subtitle text-uppercase\">$prod->desc_prod</span>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "        </div>\n";
echo "\n";
echo "        <div class=\"card_prod__body\">\n";
echo "          <img src=\"upload/$imgrow->arquivo\" alt=\"Nike 19\" class=\"card_prod__image\">\n";
         }
 } else {
    echo "<center>"."<h1>"."Não há produtos!"."<div>"."<small class="."text-muted".">"."Cadastre um para visualizar!"."</small>"."</div>"."</h1>"."</center>";
 }

echo "\n";
echo "          <span class=\"card_prod__category \">COD:$prod->codigo_prod</span>\n";
echo "            <span class=\"card_prod__category \">$prod->tamanho1_prod cm X $prod->tamanho2_prod cm</span>\n";
echo "             <span class=\"card_prod__category \">$prod->tipo_prod</span>\n";
echo "        </div>\n";
echo "      </div>\n";



}
}else{

    die($conn1->error);
}




?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para isso é necessário fazer um filtro com `LIKE`. Para fazer `match` em partes e ter mais de uma palavra no filtro vc pode usar o `%` onde quiser aceitar partes que não fazem match.

ex: `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE coluna LIKE %TERMO_1%TERMO_2%`

Ao fazer este filtro o SQL fará match com linhas onde o conteúdo tiver **TERMO_1** `E` **TERMO_2**, sendo que poderão estar no início, no meio ou no final do conteúdo.

Considerando a sua query, seria necessário substituir os espaços por `%`:
`SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE nome_prod LIKE '%".str_replace(" ", "%", $valor)."%' OR codigo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' ORDER BY codigo_prod ASC`

---

Conforme solicitado nos comentários, seguem alternativas para pegar os termos fora de ordem.

**1a alternativa**
Criar vários `LIKE` com `AND`. Funciona de forma semelhante à anterior, mas cria várias condições de busca.

ex:

```php
$busca_termos = "nome_prod LIKE '%" . str_replace(" ", "%' AND nome_prod LIKE '%", $valor) . "%'";
SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE (".$busca_termos.") OR codigo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' OR tipo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."' ORDER BY codigo_prod ASC
```

**2a alternativa**
Essa seria a alternativa mais "elegante", mas pode exigir alterações à sua tabela e até base, para habilitar o `FULL TEXT SEARCH`.

```php
SELECT *
FROM cad_produtos
WHERE
  match(nome_prod) against ('+TERMO_1 +TERMO_2' in boolean mode)
  OR codigo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."'
  OR tipo_prod LIKE '%".$valor."'
ORDER BY codigo_prod ASC
```

Note que em todos os exemplos, a busca foi alterada somente na coluna `nome_prod`.

PS: Nesta resposta não são levados em conta outros pontos que podem ser relevantes para a realização de queries com inputs dos usuários, como "como evitar SQL injection". Recomendo que pesquise no próprio SOpt sobre perguntas relacionadas ao tema.

Comment: muito obrigado era isso mesmo que eu precisava estava quebrando a cabeça pois sou iniciante

Comment: @DanielRicardo, note que ainda é NECESSÁRIO que os termos estejam em ordem. Caso seja requisito que isso seja diferente comenta aqui que passo outra alternativa. Passei essa, mais simples, por conta da descrição da pergunta.

Comment: e como seria esse de termos desordenados

Comment: blz muito obrigado estou no aguardo

Comment: muito obrigado, agora a pesquisa ficou perfeita vou da ruma pesquisada no que vc me aconselhou, muito obrigado

Comment: desculpa incomodar mas poderia me ajudar em um outra questão?

Comment: e que eu fiz uma pergunta e desde ontem ninguém respondeu para pegar campos um campo especifico quando vc clona ele com javascript

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433698/como-especificar-o-campo-input-clonado-js