# Como especificar no javascript o conjunto de inputs que foram clonados

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou montado um sistema de pedido que pega informações do banco de dados e preenche os campo com ela.

Segue o código da requisição que preenche os campo com as informações:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nome_prod").on("focusout", function(){
        var $cod_prod = $(".cod_prod");
        var $quantidade = $(".quantidade");
        var $valor_uni = $(".valor_uni");
        $.getJSON('function2.php',{ 
            nome_prod: $( this ).val() 
        },function( json ){
            $cod_prod.val( json.cod_prod );
            $quantidade.val( json.quantidade );
            $valor_uni.val( json.valor_uni );
        });
    });
});
```

O código que clona os campos:

```js
function duplicarCampos(){
    var clone = document.getElementById('origem').cloneNode(true);
    var destino = document.getElementById('destino');
    destino.appendChild (clone);

    var camposClonados = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(i=0; i<camposClonados.length;i++){
        camposClonados[i].value = '';
    }
}

function removerCampos(id){
    var node1 = document.getElementById('destino');
    node1.removeChild(node1.childNodes[0]);
}
```

e a function2.php

```php
include_once("connections/conn2.php");

function retorna($nome_prod, $conn1){
    $result_prod = "SELECT * FROM cad_produtos WHERE nome_prod = '$nome_prod' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_prod = mysqli_query($conn1, $result_prod);

    if($resultado_prod->num_rows){
        $row_prod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_prod);
        $valores['nome_prod'] = $row_prod['nome_prod'];
        $valores['quantidade'] = $row_prod['uni_med'];
        $valores['valor_uni'] = $row_prod['valor_uni'];
        $valores['cod_prod'] = $row_prod['codigo_prod'];
    }
    else{
    }

    return json_encode($valores);
}

if(isset($_GET['nome_prod'])){
    echo retorna($_GET['nome_prod'], $conn1);
}
```

Quando eu duplico o campo ele não funciona, mas quando eu clico no primeiro campo preenche todos os demais com a mesma informação contida no primeiro campo.

Os campos que são clonados estão na div origem e são clonados para div destino porém eles apenas copiam as informações do primeiro campo

```html
<div id="origem">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="cod_prod" name="cod_prod[]" placeholder="Codigo do produto" type="text" class="form-control cod_prod">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="descricao" name="nome_prod[]" placeholder="Descrição" type="text" class="form-control nome_prod">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="valor" name="valor_uni[]" placeholder="Valor" type="text" class="form-control valor_uni">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="valor" name="quantidade[]" placeholder="Quantidade" type="text" class="form-control quantidade">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="destino">
</div>
```

[image: imagem com os campo clonados]

Comment: @LeonardoButa esta pergunta que comentei com você

Comment: Não consigo analisar agora, para dar uma resposta. Mas antes que qualquer um consiga fazer isso, melhore a pergunta, ela está confusa, é difícil entender tanto o objetivo quanto o erro.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Vc tem uma página que retorna dados da sua base de dados em um formulário. Agora vc quer criar uma forma de duplicar esses dados para criar uma nova entrada na base de dados, é isso?

Comment: eu atualizei a pergunta da uma olhada ai por favor

Comment: eu tenho um código que completa os campos com informações vinda do banco, eu apenas digito o nome e as informações completam os outros campos input porem não esta completando ai quando eu clico no primeiro campo ele completa mas copiando as outras informações

Comment: Já facilitou bastante para poder entender.

Comment: Não relacionado à pergunta, mas já pro um framework para facilitar o seu trabalho? Algo como Laravel ou CakePHP, por exemplo?

Comment: então eu nunca utilizei nenhum framework, sei que facilita mas como sou iniciante tem muita coisa que preciso aprender ainda

Comment: De cara já vejo algo errado: quando vc clona a div `#origem`, vc está duplicando tanto o id `#origem` quanto os id's dos elementos dentro dessa div. Se está aprendendo HTML ainda, saiba que um id deve ser único na página, ou seja, não pode haver dois elementos com o mesmo id `#origem` (nem os outros id's). Utilize `class` em vez disso.

Comment: eu sei disso foi só desatenção mesmo

Comment: o problema é que não esta dando conflito de id como de costume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confesso que foi bastante complicado entender o que vc pretende fazer. Pela descrição na pergunta parece bem mais complicado do que realmente (acredito) que seja o objetivo. A pergunta também não está bem escrita, com muitos erros de portugês e código mal formatado. Isso tudo complica a compreensão da pergunta, afastando a possibilidade de receber respostas.

Há também inúmeros problemas no código apresentado, como repetição do ID nos inputs `<input id="valor" name="valor_uni[]"` e `<input id="valor" name="quantidade[]"` e a tentativa de pegar valores pela classe, quando há mais de um elemento com a mesma classe (ex: `var $cod_prod = $(".cod_prod");`).

Também me parece haver problemas no UX, como por exemplo ter um grupo de inputs em "origem" e vários em destino, quando parecia ser necessário ter somente um "grupo" para todas as "linhas" de inputs. Caso não seja esse o objetivo, idealmente "origem" e "destino" deveriam ser visualmente distintos. Por outro lado, caso fossem removidas todas as linhas, também não seria possível criar uma nova. Para resolver isso, seria necessário copiar os inputs a partir de um "template" e não de um div existente.

A parte de remocão também é estranha, pois remove sempre a "primeira" linha de "destino", não sendo possível remover uma específica.

Vou apresentar uma solução desconsiderando os problemas acima e acreditando que vc tem 2 objetivos:

- "Clonar" um conjunto de inputs;
- Preencher um conjunto de inputs com valores do seu backend.

```js
function duplicarCampos() {
  var destino = $('#destino');
  var clone = $('#origem').children().clone(true, true);

  // limpa valores
  clone.find('input:text').val('');

  destino.append(clone);
}

function removerCampos() {
  $('#destino').find('div:first').remove();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#duplicarCampos").click(duplicarCampos);
  $("#removerCampos").click(removerCampos);

  $(".nome_prod").on("focusout", function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('div.row');
    var cod_prod = parent.find(".cod_prod");
    var quantidade = parent.find(".quantidade");
    var valor_uni = parent.find(".valor_uni");

    cod_prod.val("json.cod_prod");
    quantidade.val("json.quantidade");
    valor_uni.val("json.valor_uni");

    //$.getJSON('function2.php', {
    //  nome_prod: $(this).val()
    //}, function(json) {
    //  cod_prod.val(json.cod_prod);
    //  quantidade.val(json.quantidade);
    //  valor_uni.val(json.valor_uni);
    //});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="duplicarCampos">Duplicar</button>
<button id="removerCampos">Remover</button>

<div id="origem">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fa fa-barcode"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input name="cod_prod[]" placeholder="Codigo do produto" type="text" class="form-control cod_prod">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input name="nome_prod[]" placeholder="Descrição" type="text" class="form-control nome_prod">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input name="valor_uni[]" placeholder="Valor" type="text" class="form-control valor_uni">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
              <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input name="quantidade[]" placeholder="Quantidade" type="text" class="form-control quantidade">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="destino"></div>
```

Comment: Realmente @tvdias tinha estes problemas mesmo, eu já estava desesperado, este não é meu código de origem mas como eu já havia testado diversas soluções acabou que o código ficou com diversos erros que ao fui percebendo aos poucos, mas obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: @DanielRicardo, caso consiga ajudar de mais alguma forma, diz

Comment: mano vlw mesmo funcionou perfeitamente agora com isso resolvido irei resolver o restante dos problemas haha

Comment: ola tudo bem, poderia me ajudar, estou com um problema porem não seria possível criar uma pergunta, por que é meio complicado de explicar, existe alguma forma de eu entrar em contato com você?